# How should I choose TVS diode capacitance for my 2MHz RS-422 application?

Tags: diodes, capacitance, rs485, tvs, rs422

I have been looking at which TVS diode to select for a protecting a set of RS-422 driver lines, however I am struggling to understand how to choose them based on the diode capacitance.
The signal will be 2MHz and be driven from a AM26C31IDBR quad RS-422 driver.

The first option I picked was this SM712, which is designed for RS-485. However, I noticed that the diode capacitance is 75 pF, which seems high however I am not sure what scale to use.

How do I calculate the maximum diode capacitance for a certain frequency signal? The lines will be 120 ohm twisted pairs

If I am correct, higher capacitance increase ESD protection but reduces frequency.

Thanks for any help

[image]

Edit: As requested here is how I will use the diodes

[image]

Comment: Please show a schematic extract of how you propose to use the TVS diodes.

Comment: @Andyaka I have edited the post to show the schematic extract

Comment: That could depend on what level of protection you want. Higher ESD levels require larger diodes that have larger capacitance. Also, your output 4 is a short circuit. And if you plan to use common off-the-shelf CAT5 cables, you might want to consider the pinout to actually use the differential pairs.

Comment: @Justme I want the highest protection available while being able to pass 2Mhz. Thank you I will take a look at the pinout I haven't considered that. I am not using the 4th channel because I am going to pass the ground reference in one of the twisted pairs

Comment: In that case, put things into context. How long a cable you need to drive? What is the capacitance of the cable? How much cable is 75pF, that's about 1.5 meters of CAT5, so if you need to go tens of meters the 75pF might be irrelevant.

Comment: Ah so you mean that the capacitance of a long cable will cause more SI problems than that of the diodes? The cat5e cable should be up to 20 metres so I guess that would be 1nF capacitance

Comment: Here is an approximative table from Toshiba, But it seems that they put the bar very low. Between 2 and 5 pF. https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/diode_tvs-diodes/what-should-i-consider-when-selecting-tvs-diodes-esd-protection-diodes-for-high-speed-signal-lines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with the voltage levels of RS422 but, I would suggest that the diodes will always be reverse biased and, [this graph from the data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/b70c/0900766b81385d5f.pdf) is worth considering: -

[image]

So, digging into what the voltage levels might be reveals this image from [here](https://www.westermo.com.sg/news-and-events/news/2019-01-31-do-industrial-networks-continue-to-utilise-rs-232-and-rs-485): -

[image]

So, you could make a decent argument that the average reverse bias is 2.5 volts and, this would make the TVS reverse biased capacitance more like 50 pF. Then, knowing that the most likely signal disruptor is an impedance mismatch, you could argue that it is the series capacitance of two 50 pF that should be considered.

This means something like 25 pF and, at 2 MHz, that's an impedance of 3183 Ω. However, you should consider that the 7th harmonic is relevant (it could be a square wave) and now, the capacitive impedance drops to 454 Ω. Compare this with a typical termination resistor of 120 Ω.

Is that significant or can it be ignored. I'd favour accepting that it won't be a problem. If in fact you mean that the data rate is 2 Mbits/sec then, the effective frequency drops to 1 MHz and this becomes even more likely not to be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could you explain to me abit more about how you considered the 7th harmonic here?

To be more specific, it needs to be able to propagate 1.25 us pulses but differentiate between a 33% and 66% duty cycle pulse (I am targeting WS2812B LEDs)

Comment: The 7th harmonic is a good rule of thumb for ensuring you cover the bases when dealing with signals that have a decent rise and fall time (i.e. are square-ish). If in doubt, try simulating the effect @FergusRooney

Comment: @FergusRooney if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.